# Jquery disable Span with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disabled-control

Trying to disable this span

```
<span id='downloadTestModal1' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDownloadTestdata" class="fa fa-download"  onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Download" data-tooltip="tooltip" ></span>
```

So far tried this, but id does not work for me.

```
    $('#downloadTestModal1').unbind("click");
    $("#downloadTestModal1").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#downloadTestModal1').toggleClass("disabled");
```

Are there any other methods?

Comment: Disabled is for form elements, what behaviour are you trying to disable?

Comment: Are you working with Bootstrap Modal Control ?

Comment: @mattytommo Now it is launching modal on click, I just want to click option be disabled until I allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tw2L2ttw/1/

clear or set 'data-toggle' to disable or enable modal pop up

```
//## disable
$('#downloadTestModal1').attr('data-toggle','');

//## enable 
$('#downloadTestModal1').attr('data-toggle','modal');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
$('#downloadTestModal1').preventDefault();
```

Since preventDefault() works only on elements with default event. In this case there is no default event for span element. Sorry for that. I used it earlier, but that was on click event atached to a element

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code and why it would answer the asker's question.

Comment: That was my mistake. Since `preventDefault()` works only on elements with default event. In this case there is no default event for `span` element. Sorry for that. I used it earlier, but that was on click event atached to an element